# Reduce OpenMP fork/join overhead on deeply nested for loops

Tags: optimization, openmp, c++14

I'm trying to optimise my timestep method which resides on an adaptive mesh. It's set up with three classes: Mesh (the base class), Level (identifying the level of the adaptive grid) and Rectangle (many of which lie on a given level, and hold all the data for my problem).

The brunt of the work to advance the timestep resides in the function `FCTTimeStep` within the Rectangle class, which I've been able to get running quite efficiently (according to Intel's VTune) over multiple threads using standard parallel for pragmas on the tightest loops:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{      
    #pragma omp for schedule(guided)
    for (int i=1; i<nx; i++) {
        #pragma ivdep
        for (int j=0; j<np; j++) {
            // Work
        }
    }
    #pragma omp for schedule(guided)
    for (int i=1; i<dx; i++) {
        #pragma ivdep
        for (int j=0; j<dp; j++) {
            // More Work
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me little to no spin time and is working fine. The problem is that I'm calling `FCTTimeStep` millions of times throughout the programs runtime. A manager class calls its `Advance` function:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {  //RungeKutta Steps, must be sequential
    EMSolver->AssembleRhoAndJ(); //Single thread
    EMSolver->UpdatePotential(); //Single thread

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < settings.q.size(); j++) {
        meshes[j]->Advance(timeStep, i); //Mesh call
    }
    settings.UpdateTime(i, timeStep); //Single thread
    EMSolver->RGKStep(i, timeStep); //Single thread
}
```

`Mesh::Advance` calls each `Level::Advance` in the mesh (via a for loops - multiple times, with single threaded work in between), then for each level we call all the rectangles `Rectangle::FCTTimeStep` methods (again via a for loop). There are between 3 and 10 threaded for loops called each time `FCTTimeStep` is accessed - which leads to a significant overhead from calling `clone` (due to constant fork/joins). A profiled test run with 4 threads tells me 25% of the runtime is taken up by this, 12 cores it was more that 60%.

What I would like to try is cage my entire program in a parallel pragma

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{      
    while (t < T_stop) {
        double dt_adaptive = CalculateDt(settings.cfl);
        SM.Advance(dt_adaptive); //Call to the managers' Advance function
        #pragma omp single
        {
            //Single work
        }
    }
}
```

and serve the workers to the the orphaned pragmas in `FCTTimeStep`. This will increase thread spin time dramatically due to the single work regions, but should give me a better general runtime.

My question is therefore the following: **Is there a way to get OpenMP to send workers solely to threaded regions and operate in single mode otherwise?** Otherwise the parallel region is going to make each thread call the advance method and I'm unsure how to tackle setting up the correct pragmas all the way down the nested for loop structure over multiple classes to stop that.

I've seen the construction:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single nowait
{
    #pragma omp task 
    // Work
    #pragma omp task
    // More Work
    #pragma omp taskwait
    // Single Work
}
```

ie gate the whole region with single, then call tasks, but this doesn't seem to work with the for pragma. So perhaps a better question could be **Can the *for* pragma be set up to work similar to the *task* pragma?**

Any general assistance or links to appropriate information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What compiler (OMP runtime) is this? I would assume most compilers use threadpools internally even if you end/recreate teams.

Comment: I'm using intel compilers (so linking libiomp5). I've been looking deeper into the problem since I asked this question and I can confirm that a threadpool is used here. I may be interpreting the results from my profiler incorrectly, so I've asked another question at the intel forums about that: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/topic/712496